# Is there a way to use signal.fftconvolve with an array of different kernels?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, signals, convolution

I am using the python package scipy for image processing, specifically scipy.signal.fftconvolve(in1, in2) to blur my image.
where in1 is your image (2d numpy array) , and in2 is kernel (much smaller 2d numpy array)

When this function is called, it goes through each pixel and blurs it depending on what the kernel values are.

However, what I want is for fftconvolve() to take in an array of kernels rather than a single kernel. One kernel for each pixel. But I haven't found a way to convolve with more than one kernel.

**In simple terms I want each pixel to have a different blur value and direction, and right now I can only hack it so the entire image is blurred the same value.** I am open to other methods other then just fftconvolve.

Comment: A different kernel at each pixel implies the operator is no longer linear, and therefore cannot be implemented though the FFT. So `fftconvolve` will never be able to do such a thing. It also is a rather uncommon operator, so it likely doesn't have a standard implementation, you'll have to write your own using a loop though all pixels of your image.

Comment: Ok thank you for the information. However it makes me wonder how do programs like photoshop, perform actions like blurring across a path, where each pixel must have a different kernel value in order to achieve the effect? They must be using some different method, any insight on that?

Comment: Not sure which filter you're talking about, but it must be implemented like any other filter: looping over each pixel that must be modified.